# Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing ') - As far as I can tell this is correct

Tags: formula

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Current_Option_Year__c, "4")
    ANDIF(
        ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.of_Option_Years__c, "4")
        "True", 
        null
    )
)
```

Comment: Having `"True"` as an output is a major code smell. Curious where you found any indication `ANDIF` is a function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working within Salesforce, what you have is not correct and there are several syntax errors.

- The `IF()` formula function takes 3 arguments. The condition, the value if the condition is true (the "then"), the value if the condition is false (the "else"). All 3 are required, and they must be in that order.
- There is no `ANDIF()` function, you could separate those to make `AND()` and `IF()`, but doing so wouldn't make any sense
- You are missing commas between arguments. The commas are required.
- If this formula is for a field on the `Opportunity` object itself, you don't need to prefix the field name with `Opportunity`. If this formula is for a field on the `OpportunityLineItem`, `Quote`, or perhaps one of a few other standard SObjects, then prefixing with the relationship name `Opportunity` would be correct.

You should go through the [Formulas and Validations module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) on trailhead to get a basic understanding of how formulas work. After that, you should reference [Formula Operators and Functions by Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) to learn about the specifics of each function (most of the functions have decent usage examples).

To have multiple conditions be tested for an `IF()`, you'd either need to:

- Use boolean functions (`AND()`, `OR()`, `NOT()`) to tie multiple conditions together
- Nest another `IF()` in the "then" or "else" for more complex sets of conditions

In your case, with the two simple conditions you're checking, you'd simply `AND()` them together. e.g.

```
IF(
    AND(
        <picklist value check 1>,
        <picklist value check 2>
    ),
    <value if true>,
    <value if false>
)
```

Comment: The general lack of detail makes it hard to suggest anything more specific, though using an `IF()` to return `"true"` is a red flag (albeit a small one). If you only need to get true/false out of this (i.e. for a checkbox type forrmula field), then the `IF()` is not necessary. `IF(true, true, false)` => `true`. `IF(false, true, false)` => `false`. Similar story for chekcing equivalence of booleans. `true == true` => `true`, `false == true` => `false`. `true != true` => `false`, `false != true` => `true`.